# Is it possible to get a place by ID from the Azure Maps API?

Tags: azure, rest, api, maps

The Azure Maps REST API returns an ID for each place, for example when using the "Get Search POI Category" service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchpoicategory). Is it possible to later retrieve a specific place by its ID again?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't... Which is quite stupid. There is a suggestion to include it however: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909172-azure-maps/suggestions/35098288-ability-to-get-poi-information-using-it-s-id-and-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.